# NET6 Make appsettings.json required instead of the default optional

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

WebAppllicationBuilder builds Configuration and adds some providers by default, like:

- JsonConfigurationProvider for "appsettings.json" or
- JsonConfigurationProvider for "secrets.json"

They are added with parameter optional: true

I need "appsettings.json" to te required, not optional. Sure, I can add additional json file providers and map the same files again with new settings. But code would look better, if there is a way to modify default providers and set one of them optional: false.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration     
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        // here I need to add "secrets.json" again, because secrets are loaded by
        // default json provider but overwritten by above
        // .AddUserSecrets<Program>(optional: true)
        // (I put the same key in both files, just marked "from-secrets" in "appsettings.json" to indicate what is needed)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables("whatever_");
```

How to modify options of default providers?

Marek

Answer (score 2):

My current hack is

```cs
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((_, builder) =>
    {
        builder
            .Sources.OfType<JsonConfigurationSource>()
            .First(x => x.Path == "appsettings.json")
            .Optional = false;
    })
```